# tooltipFormat doesn't work for anychart.line()

Tags: javascript, tooltip, anychart

I found an interesting bug I guess...

If I create a lineChart and want to change the Tooltip Title with a format, it does not work.

```
chart = anychart.line();
var seriesData_1 = dataSet.mapAs({x: [0], value: [1]});
series_1 = chart.line(seriesData_1);

chart.tooltip().titleFormat('{%x}'); //works
chart.tooltip().titleFormat('{%value}');  //does not work
```

I'm on AnyChart Version: Version: 7.14.3.1436

Comment: the answer was updated, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an unexpected behavior or a bug. The thing is the line chart provides union displayMode for tooltips as a default. In this case tooltip body related to series, but the title to the chart which is a common thing for all series.
So, to achieve your aim you should switch displayMode to 'separated' or 'single'. 
Please, check a sample below for details

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
  
    var dataSet = anychart.data.set([['1', 10],
                          ['2',12]]);
  
chart = anychart.line();
  var seriesData_1 = dataSet.mapAs({x: 0, value: 1});
  
 series_1 = chart.line(seriesData_1);
  
  var tooltip = chart.tooltip();
  tooltip.displayMode('single');
  tooltip.titleFormat("value: {%value}");
  
  
    chart.container("container").draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.anychart.com/css/7.14.3/anychart-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/js/8.1.0/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```